# Array.push() if does not exist?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, push, not-exists

How can I push into an array if neither values exist? Here is my array:

```
[
    { name: "tom", text: "tasty" },
    { name: "tom", text: "tasty" },
    { name: "tom", text: "tasty" },
    { name: "tom", text: "tasty" },
    { name: "tom", text: "tasty" }
]
```

If I tried to push again into the array with either `name: "tom"` or `text: "tasty"`, I don't want anything to happen... but if neither of those are there then I want it to `.push()`

How can I do this?

Comment: Use a dictionary (hash/tree) instead of an array.

Comment: Are all these available in javascript?

Comment: Yes: http://code.google.com/p/jshashtable

Comment: use a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

Comment: Set doesn't work with array of objects

Comment: [`[...new Set([...someArray, someElement])]`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75270350/1045881)

Answer (score 130, accepted):

You could extend the Array prototype with a custom method:

```
// check if an element exists in array using a comparer function
// comparer : function(currentElement)
Array.prototype.inArray = function(comparer) { 
    for(var i=0; i < this.length; i++) { 
        if(comparer(this[i])) return true; 
    }
    return false; 
}; 

// adds an element to the array if it does not already exist using a comparer 
// function
Array.prototype.pushIfNotExist = function(element, comparer) { 
    if (!this.inArray(comparer)) {
        this.push(element);
    }
}; 

var array = [{ name: "tom", text: "tasty" }];
var element = { name: "tom", text: "tasty" };
array.pushIfNotExist(element, function(e) { 
    return e.name === element.name && e.text === element.text; 
});
```

Comment: I think your camparer (comparator?) should take two arguments, this would simplify the case when the added value is inline and not in a variable you can access in your function.

array.pushIfNotExist({ name: "tom", text: "tasty" }, function(a,b){ return a.name === b.name && a.text === b.text; });

Comment: I'm wondering why this isn't native to the language - forget how it's implemented - the idea of 'adding only if unique' is so fundamental as to be assumed to exist.

Comment: It is better to extend Array prototype with JavaScript 1.6 method IndexOf instead of your inArray.

Comment: `Array.findIndex()` is a built-in JS function that will achieve the same as your code does.

Comment: `Array.findIndex()` does not work in IE, but the provided function does.

Comment: Extending built-in objects directly is a bad practice.

Comment: JS [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) can be used.

Answer (score 616):

For an array of strings (but not an array of objects), you can check if an item exists by calling `.indexOf()` and if it doesn't then just **push** the item into the array:

```js
var newItem = "NEW_ITEM_TO_ARRAY";
var array = ["OLD_ITEM_1", "OLD_ITEM_2"];

array.indexOf(newItem) === -1 ? array.push(newItem) : console.log("This item already exists");

console.log(array)
```

Comment: In the initial question, the values of the array are objects, not strings (and this solution doesn't work as is if values are objects).

Comment: Try `if (a.indexOf({ name: "tom", text: "tasty" })!=-1) a.push({ name: "tom", text: "tasty" })` twice. It will add a 'similar' object twice.

Comment: [`[...new Set([...someArray, someElement])]`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75270350/1045881)

Answer (score 195):

It is quite easy to do using the `Array.findIndex` function, which takes a function as an argument:

```
let arrayObj = [
  { name: "bar", text: "sour" },
  { name: "tom", text: "tasty" },
  { name: "tom", text: "tasty" },
];

// Find the index of an object with a specific property value
let index = arrayObj.findIndex((item) => item.name === "bar");

// Check if the object with the specified property value exists in the array
if (index === -1) {
  // If not found, push a new object with the desired properties
  arrayObj.push({ name: "bar", text: "sour" });
} else {
  // If found, log a message indicating that the object already exists
  console.log("Object already exists");
}

// Display the updated array
console.log(arrayObj);
```

Answer (score 50):

I know this is a very old question, but if you're using ES6 you can use a very small version:

```
[1,2,3].filter(f => f !== 3).concat([3])
```

Very easy, at first add a filter which removes the item - if it already exists, and then add it via a concat.

Here is a more realistic example:

```
const myArray = ['hello', 'world']
const newArrayItem

myArray.filter(f => f !== newArrayItem).concat([newArrayItem])
```

If you're array contains objects you could adapt the filter function like this:

```
someArray.filter(f => f.some(s => s.id === myId)).concat([{ id: myId }])
```

Comment: Quite an elegant solution here. Thanks!

Comment: Note this won't retain the strings in the order in which they're first seen

Comment: I used this solution but needed to make this change:

`let myArray = ['hello', 'world']
const newArrayItem

myArray = myArray.filter(f => f !== newArrayItem).concat([newArrayItem])
`

Answer (score 40):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/

```
var cleanArray = $.unique(clutteredArray);
```

you might be interested in makeArray too

The previous example is best in saying that check if it exists before pushing.
I see in hindsight it also states you can declare it as part of the prototype (I guess that's aka Class Extension), so no big enhancement below.

Except I'm not sure if indexOf is a faster route then inArray? probably.

```
Array.prototype.pushUnique = function (item){
    if(this.indexOf(item) == -1) {
    //if(jQuery.inArray(item, this) == -1) {
        this.push(item);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: From the jQuery link: `Note that this only works on arrays of DOM elements, not strings or numbers.`
Also, indexOf doesn't work in IE8 :(

Comment: You could use lodash _.indexOf, that will work in IE8

Answer (score 39):

Like this?

```
var item = "Hello World";
var array = [];
if (array.indexOf(item) === -1) array.push(item);
```

With object

```
var item = {name: "tom", text: "tasty"}
var array = [{}]
if (!array.find(o => o.name === 'tom' && o.text === 'tasty'))
    array.push(item)
```

Comment: `array.find` is a bad idea because it searches the entire array. Use `findIndex`, which only searches until the first occurrence.

Comment: @K48 according to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33759573/5227365 "find" stops after it found the item

Comment: as @Pascal said it returns right after it finds a truthy value - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#description

Answer (score 33):

**Push dynamically**

```
var a = [
  {name:"bull", text: "sour"},
  {name: "tom", text: "tasty" },
  {name: "Jerry", text: "tasty" }
]

function addItem(item) {
  var index = a.findIndex(x => x.name == item.name)
  if (index === -1) {
    a.push(item);
  }else {
    console.log("object already exists")
  }
}

var item = {name:"bull", text: "sour"};
addItem(item);
```

**In simple method**

```
var item = {name:"bull", text: "sour"};
a.findIndex(x => x.name == item.name) == -1 ? a.push(item) : console.log("object already exists")
```

**If the array contains only primitive types/ simple array**

```
var b = [1, 7, 8, 4, 3];
var newItem = 6;
b.indexOf(newItem) === -1 && b.push(newItem);
```

Comment: Health to your hands.Simple and beautiful solution @Gopala raja naika

Comment: This a.findIndex(x => x.name == item.name) is really simple and very useful. Thanks

Answer (score 30):

Easy code, if 'indexOf' returns '-1' it means that element is not inside the array then the condition '=== -1' retrieve true/false.

The '&&' operator means 'and', so if the first condition is true we push it to the array.

```
array.indexOf(newItem) === -1 && array.push(newItem);
```

Comment: There are other accepted answers that provide the OP's question, and they were posted some time ago. When posting an answer [see: How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), please make sure you add either a new solution, or a substantially better explanation, especially when answering older questions.

Comment: I think this is a good answer and a better solution so I up-voted it. I don't understand @ help-info.de comment, particularly as there are other answers here which are terrible.

Comment: does not solve the question, once it will not work if there are objects in the array

Comment: It would be `array.indexOf(newItem) !== -1 && array.push(newItem);`

Answer (score 27):

Use a js library like [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) for these reasons exactly. Use: union: Computes the union of the passed-in arrays: the list of unique items, in order, that are present in one or more of the arrays.

```
_.union([1, 2, 3], [101, 2, 1, 10], [2, 1]);
=> [1, 2, 3, 101, 10]
```

Comment: Note, this returns a new array and doesn't actually push to an existing array.

Comment: IMHO there's really no need to bring in a framework to test against something so simple

Answer (score 24):

I would suggest you use a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set),

Sets only allow unique entries, which automatically solves your problem.

Sets can be declared like so:

```
const baz = new Set(["Foo","Bar"])
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @Michael. Good solution for when we want to maintain distinct data with minimum effort. FWIW, it's important to note that array performance is better as it requires less CPU to fetch the element when it's needed.

Comment: The question asks about `Array.push`, so `Set.add` is the equivalent to that.

Comment: @BenjaminLöffel I would expect that Set is implemented as a hash, which would perform about as well as an array for iteration over items.  And of course it would perform much better at inserting without duplicates.

Comment: I'm glad I scrolled down to check more answers!

Answer (score 15):

My choice was to use `.includes()` extending the Array.prototype as @Darrin Dimitrov suggested:

```
Array.prototype.pushIfNotIncluded = function (element) {
    if (!this.includes(element)) {
      this.push(element);
    }
}
```

Just remembering that `includes` comes from es6 and does not work on IE:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone has less complicated requirements, here is my adaptation of the answer for a simple string array:

```
Array.prototype.pushIfNotExist = function(val) {
    if (typeof(val) == 'undefined' || val == '') { return; }
    val = $.trim(val);
    if ($.inArray(val, this) == -1) {
        this.push(val);
    }
};
```

Update: Replaced indexOf and trim with jQuery alternatives for IE8 compatability

Comment: it is a nice solution, but why use trim?

Answer (score 4):

### Add if not already in list

##### For a list of simple values, it's a one-liner...

```js
[...new Set([...someArray, someElement])]
```

JavaScript Usage:

```js
var myArray = ['bill','bob']
var alreadyIn = [...new Set([...myArray, 'bob'])] // ['bill','bob']
var notAlreadyIn = [...new Set([...myArray, 'peter'])] // ['bill','bob','peter']
```

TypeScript ext (note **include** vs **includes**):

```js
interface Array<T> {
  include(element: T): Array<T>
}
Array.prototype.include = function (element: any): any[] {
  return [...new Set([...this, obj])]
}
```

##### ...but for objects, it's more complicated

```js
[...new Set([...someArray.map((o) => JSON.stringify(o)),
    JSON.stringify(someElement)]).map((o) => JSON.parse(o))
```

TypeScript ext to handle anything:

```js
Array.prototype.include = function (element: any): any[] {
  if (element && typeof element === 'object')
    return [
      ...new Set([
        ...this.map((o) => JSON.stringify(o)),
        JSON.stringify(element),
      ]),
    ].map((o) => JSON.parse(o))
  else return [...new Set([...this, element])]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In case you need something simple without wanting to extend the Array prototype:

```
// Example array
var array = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}];

function pushIfNew(obj) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i].id === obj.id) { // modify whatever property you need
      return;
    }
  }
  array.push(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I used map and reduce to do this in the case where you wish to search by the a specific property of an object, useful as doing direct object equality will often fail.

```
var newItem = {'unique_id': 123};
var searchList = [{'unique_id' : 123}, {'unique_id' : 456}];

hasDuplicate = searchList
   .map(function(e){return e.unique_id== newItem.unique_id})
   .reduce(function(pre, cur) {return pre || cur});

if (hasDuplicate) {
   searchList.push(newItem);
} else {
   console.log("Duplicate Item");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the findIndex method with a callback function and its "this" parameter.

Note: old browsers don't know findIndex but a polyfill is available.

Sample code (take care that in the original question, a new object is pushed only if neither of its data is in previoulsy pushed objects):

```
var a=[{name:"tom", text:"tasty"}], b;
var magic=function(e) {
    return ((e.name == this.name) || (e.text == this.text));
};

b={name:"tom", text:"tasty"};
if (a.findIndex(magic,b) == -1)
    a.push(b); // nothing done
b={name:"tom", text:"ugly"};
if (a.findIndex(magic,b) == -1)
    a.push(b); // nothing done
b={name:"bob", text:"tasty"};
if (a.findIndex(magic,b) == -1)
    a.push(b); // nothing done
b={name:"bob", text:"ugly"};
if (a.findIndex(magic,b) == -1)
    a.push(b); // b is pushed into a
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about speed, but `stringification` + `indexOf` is a simple approach. Start with turning your array into a string:

```
let strMyArray = JSON.stringify(myArray);
```

Then for a series of attribute-value pairs you can use:

```
if (strMyArray.indexOf('"name":"tom"') === -1 && strMyArray.indexOf('"text":"tasty"') === -1) {
   myArray.push({ name: "tom", text: "tasty" });
}
```

Finding a whole object is simpler:

```
if (strMyArray.indexOf(JSON.stringify(objAddMe) === -1) { 
   myArray.push(objAddMe);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

### Removing duplicates after pushing

If you already have an array containing duplicates, transform the array of objects into an array of strings, and then use the `Set()` function to eliminate duplicates:

```js
let arr_obj = [
    { name: "tom", text: "tasty" }, 
    { name: "tom", text: "tasty" }
]

let arr_str = arr_obj.map(JSON.stringify)

let arr_unique = [...new Set(arr_str)].map(JSON.parse)
```

### Checking before pushing

If you don't have duplicates so far and you want to check for duplicates before pushing a new element:

```js
let arr_obj = [
    { name: "tom", text: "tasty" },
    { name: "tim", text: "tusty" }
]

let new_obj = { name: "tom", text: "tasty" }

let arr_str = arr_obj.map(JSON.stringify)

!arr_str.includes(JSON.stringify(new_obj)) && arr_obj.push(new_obj)
```

Comment: `"use strict"; const EYE_BLEEDING_FULL_OF_COMMENTS_CODE = true;`

Comment: Yeap, you are right, I'm going to edit the answer.

Comment: :) yeah, that nice) now I understand your idea at a glance

Answer (score 2):

I guess i am too late to answer here however this is what i finally came up with for a mail manager i wrote. Works that's all i need.

```js
window.ListManager = [];
$('#add').click(function(){
//Your Functionality
  let data =Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1 
  
  if (window.ListManager.includes(data)){
      console.log("data exists in list")
  }else{
       window.ListManager.push(data);
  }
  
  
  $('#result').text(window.ListManager);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Unique List</h1>

<p id="result"></p>
<button id="add">Add to List</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

a is the array of objects you have

```
a.findIndex(x => x.property=="WhateverPropertyYouWantToMatch") <0 ? 
a.push(objectYouWantToPush) : console.log("response if object exists");
```

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer to use native js `Array.prototype.some()` even in jQ env
Docs: [w3s `some`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_some.asp) or [mdn `some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```
let arr = [
    { name: "tom", text: "tasty" },
    { name: "tom", text: "tasty" }
];
let oneMore = { name: "tom", text: "tasty" };
!arr.some(i => i.name == oneMore.name && i.text == oneMore.text)
  && arr.push(oneMore);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a way to do it in one line for two arrays:

```
const startArray = [1,2,3,4]
const newArray = [4,5,6]

const result = [...startArray, ...newArray.filter(a => !startArray.includes(a))]

console.log(result);
//Result: [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Answer (score 1):

The question was a litle bit old, but that my option :

```
    let finalTab = [{id: 1, name: 'dupont'}, {id: 2, name: 'tintin'}, {id: 3, name:'toto'}]; // Your array of object you want to populate with distinct data
    const tabToCompare = [{id: 1, name: 'dupont'}, {id: 4, name: 'tata'}]; // A array with 1 new data and 1 is contain into finalTab
    
    finalTab.push(
      ...tabToCompare.filter(
        tabToC => !finalTab.find(
          finalT => finalT.id === tabToC.id)
      )
    ); // Just filter the first array, and check if data into tabToCompare is not into finalTab, finally push the result of the filters

    console.log(finalTab); // Output : [{id: 1, name: 'dupont'}, {id: 2, name: 'tintin'}, {id: 3, name: 'toto'}, {id: 4, name: 'tata'}];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working func for an objects comparison. In some cases you might have lot of fields to compare.
Simply loop the array and call this function with a existing items and new item.

```
 var objectsEqual = function (object1, object2) {
        if(!object1 || !object2)
            return false;
        var result = true;
        var arrayObj1 = _.keys(object1);
        var currentKey = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < arrayObj1.length; i++) {
            currentKey = arrayObj1[i];
            if (object1[currentKey] !== null && object2[currentKey] !== null)
                if (!_.has(object2, currentKey) ||
                    !_.isEqual(object1[currentKey].toUpperCase(), object2[currentKey].toUpperCase()))
                    return false;
        }
        return result;
    };
```

Comment: use native `forEach` instead of `for` ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
someArray = [{a: 'a1 value', b: {c: "c1 value"},
             {a: 'a2 value', b: {c: "c2 value"}]
newObject = {a: 'a2 value', b: {c: "c2 value"}}

//New object which needs check for duplicity

let isExists = checkForExists(newObject) {
    return someArray.some(function(el) {
        return el.a === newObject.a && el.b.c === newObject.b.c;
    });
}
// write your logic here 
// if isExists is true then already object in an array else you can add
```

Comment: Great use of `.some`! You're missing the closing `}` on your two array objects though.

Answer (score 0):

I hade this issue and I made a simple prototype, use it if you liked it

```js
Array.prototype.findOrPush = function(predicate, fallbackVal) {
    let item = this.find(predicate)
    if(!item){
        item = fallbackVal
        this.push(item)
    }
    return item
}

let arr = [{id: 1}]
let item = arr.findOrPush(e => e.id == 2, {id: 2})
console.log(item) // {id: 2} 

// will not push and just return existing value
arr.findOrPush(e => e.id == 2, {id: 2}) 
conslog.log(arr)  // [{id: 1}, {id: 2}]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your project includes [lodash](https://lodash.com/) it will be simple by using `unionBy` method

```
import {unionBy} from "lodash";

let arrayObj = [
    { name: "jhon", text: "guitar"},
    { name: "paul", text: "bass" },
    { name: "george", text: "guitar" }
];

// this object will be added to the array
arrayObj = unionBy(arrayObj, [{name: 'ringo', text: 'drums'}], 'name')

// this object will be ignored because already exists  
arrayObj = unionBy(arrayObj, [{name: "jhon", text: "guitar"}], 'name')
```

Answer (score -1):

Short example:

```
if (typeof(arr[key]) === "undefined") {
  arr.push(key);
}
```

Comment: Not correct.  We are not interested in pushing the key, we want to push a name-value pair, but only if it does not already exist.

Answer (score -2):

You can check the array using foreach and then pop the item if it exists otherwise add new item...

sample newItemValue &submitFields are key,value pairs

```
> //submitFields existing array
>      angular.forEach(submitFields, function(item) {
>                   index++; //newItemValue new key,value to check
>                     if (newItemValue == item.value) {
>                       submitFields.splice(index-1,1);
>                         
>                     } });

                submitFields.push({"field":field,"value":value});
```