# Check if a string is in a list or not (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, java, list, salesforce

I have a list as below:

```
var myList = [{type:'Prospect__c', typeName__c:'high_school', },
{type:'Procedure__c', typeName__c:'in_program', },
{type:'Procedure__c', typeName__c:'attention_plz', }]
```

I want to check if `in_program` (which is present in my list), exists in my list or not?
I've used different types of codes in order to get the result but I did not succeed.

Here are some of my tries:

> if (myList.indexOf('in_program')>0)
>
> if (myList.indexOf(typeName__c:'in_program')>0)
>
> if (myList.indexOf(" typeName__c:'in_program' ")>0)

Comment: do you need the index or just know if its there?

Comment: @corn3lius I just want to know if it exists or not.

Comment: `JSON.stringify(myList).indexOf(searchString) > -1`

Comment: use Array.prototype.find

Comment: @reshad a useful reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22844560/check-if-object-value-exists-within-a-javascript-array-of-objects-and-if-not-add

Comment: @Hoyen if its just about finding existance of value, I'd suggest `array.some`

Comment: @Rajesh Thanks ! your solution worked !

Comment: @reshad Glad I could help! Also I have added an answer and have explained few methods based on cases. Hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following approach in different scenario:

#### JSON.stringify

If its just about finding availability, you can get JSON string and then check in it.

As correctly pointed by [corn3lius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/130453/corn3lius), just checking search value will search in keys as well. You can wrap searchValue in `":..."` and this will only search in values

```js
var myList = [{type:'Prospect__c', typeName__c:'high_school', },
{type:'Procedure__c', typeName__c:'in_program', },
{type:'Procedure__c', typeName__c:'attention_plz', }]
var searchVal = 'in_program';

var exist= JSON.stringify(myList).indexOf(":\"" + searchVal + "\"") > -1;

console.log(exist)
```

#### Array.some

An alternate could be using array function if you know the exact key to lookup

```js
var myList = [{type:'Prospect__c', typeName__c:'high_school', },
{type:'Procedure__c', typeName__c:'in_program', },
{type:'Procedure__c', typeName__c:'attention_plz', }]
var searchVal = 'in_program';

var exist= myList.some(function(o){ return o.typeName__c === searchVal });

console.log(exist)
```

#### Array.find

If you want to find first object where value matches, you should use `Array.find`

```js
var myList = [{type:'Prospect__c', typeName__c:'high_school', },
{type:'Procedure__c', typeName__c:'in_program', },
{type:'Procedure__c', typeName__c:'attention_plz', }]
var searchVal = 'in_program';

var exist= myList.find(function(o){ return o.typeName__c === searchVal });

console.log(exist)
```

#### Array.filter

If you want to find all objects where value matches, you should use `Array.filter`

```js
var myList = [{type:'Prospect__c', typeName__c:'high_school', },
{type:'Procedure__c', typeName__c:'in_program', },
{type:'Procedure__c', typeName__c:'attention_plz', }]
var searchVal = 'Procedure__c';

var exist= myList.filter(function(o){ return o.type === searchVal });

console.log(exist)
```

Comment: stringify solution doesn't account for the search result being in a key or the value of another key.

Comment: @corn3lius Thanks for pointing it out. I have updated my answer and have credited you.

Answer (score 2):

There are a bunch of different strategies you can follow, but `indexOf` would only work if you were looking for the exact same root object, not one of its properties

A good approach would be with filter:

```
var filteredItems = myList.filter(function(a) { 
  return a.typeName__c === 'in_program' 
})
console.log(filteredItems.length === 0) // false
```

This will return a new collection with the items filtered by the returned value of the callback. Then, you check the length and see if it's 0 or greater.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
var isInList = myList.some(function (obj) {
    return 'in_program' === obj.typeName__c;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the code below:

```
var myList = [{type:'Prospect__c', typeName__c:'high_school', },
{type:'Procedure__c', typeName__c:'in_program', },
{type:'Procedure__c', typeName__c:'attention_plz', }];

var length = myList.length;

for(i = 0; i < length ; i++){

    if(myList[i].typeName__c == 'in_program')
  {
    alert("true");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var entry = mylist.find(function(e){ return e.typeName__c === 'in_program'; });
if( entry ) {
   // found object in list 
}
```

documented here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: `mylist.find(e => e.typeName__c === 'in__program');`