# Check if one element exists in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming

I have the following array of objects:

```
var memberships = [
  {
    id: 1,
    type: 'guest'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    type: 'member'
  }
];
```

How can I verify if such an array has at least one element with type 'member'?

Note that the array can also have no elements.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if object value exists within a Javascript array of objects and if not add a new object to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22844560/check-if-object-value-exists-within-a-javascript-array-of-objects-and-if-not-add)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may help

```
let resultArray=memberships.filter(function(item) {
     return item["type"] === 'member';
});
```

the result array holds the data of the objects that has type member

Answer (score 15):

Use `array.some()`

```js
var memberships = [{
    id: 1,
    type: 'guest'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    type: 'member'
  }
];

var status = memberships.some(function(el) {
  return (el.type === 'member');
});

/*
  // Simplified format using arrow functions
  var status = memberships.some(el => el.type === 'member')
*/
console.log(status);
```

### Array.some()

***Array.some()** executes the callback function once for each element present in the array until it finds one where callback returns a truthy value. If such an element is found, some() immediately returns true. Otherwise, some() returns false.*

Answer (score 7):

You can use `Array#some` method:

`const memberExists = memberships.some(member => member.type === 'member');`

Then, `if(memberExists) ...`

Comment: Thanks for this! Very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array#some`

```js
var memberships = [
  {
    id: 1,
    type: 'guest'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    type: 'member'
  }
];

console.log(memberships.some(m=>m.type==='member'));
```

Comment: `Array.prototype.some()` would likely be faster/cheaper since it doesn't need to process the whole array.

Comment: @DavidThomas That's true

Answer (score 1):

You can also use find, which returns the first object if found else undefined.

```
let a = memberships.find(o => o.type === 'member');

if (a) {
  ...do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var memberships = [
        {
            "Name": "family_name",
            "Value": "Krishna"
        },
        {
            "Name": "email",
            "Value": "harikrishnar88@gmail.com"
        }
    ];

    let resultArray=memberships.filter(function(item) {
      return item["Name"] === 'email';
});
```