# check if dictionary object in array contains certain value in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array, like so:

```
 const myArray = [{key1: "value1", key2: "value2"}, {key1: "value4", key2: "value8"},
  {key1: "value1", key2: "value3"}, {key1: "value1", key2: "value32"}]
```

I need to loop through the array, and see if ANY item in the array has a certain value. I have looked through other questions and most loop through and create variables, however I am not allowed to use var (ES6 something, I'm a js noob  and am not sure, just was told to never use var, always const). Basically I need something like this:

```
if (myArray.contains(object where key1=="value2")) {
  // do something
}
```

I would like for the function to return true/false as well, not the object itself.

thanks

Comment: `myArray.some(o => o.key1 == 'value2')`… https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

Comment: Another possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22844560/check-if-object-value-exists-within-a-javascript-array-of-objects-and-if-not-add

Comment: @deceze Not sure how you think the question you linked is a duplicate. This question is about a dict, the other is about an array. Pretty obviously distinct. I wish Stack let people flag closures/duplicate marks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To check if object exists in array you can use `some()` that returns `true/false`

```js
const myArray = [{key1: "value1", key2: "value2"}, {key1: "value4", key2: "value8"}, {key1: "value1", key2: "value3"}, {key1: "value1", key2: "value32"}]
  
if(myArray.some(e => e.key1 == 'value1')) {
  console.log('Exists');
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply use with [`Array#map`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjH7KDGnuDTAhXCQI8KHbwMBi0QFgghMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fmap&usg=AFQjCNG-88X_4BP621jc1yLUJwBxSXgcxg) and [`includes()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp)

```js
 const myArray = [{key1: "value1", key2: "value2"}, {key1: "value4", key2: "value8"}, {key1: "value1", key2: "value3"}, {key1: "value1", key2: "value32"}]
console.log(myArray.map(a=>a.key1).includes('value2'))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some?v=control).

Code:

```js
const myArray = [{key1: "value1", key2: "value2"}, {key1: "value4", key2: "value8"}, {key1: "value1", key2: "value3"}, {key1: "value1", key2: "value32"}]

const isKey1Value2 = myArray.some(el => 'value2' === el.key1)

console.log(isKey1Value2)
```