# Find a matching value in Vue component

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have passed this collection (postFavourite) to my vue component via props.

[{"id":1,"user_id":1,"post_id":2,"created_at":"2018-07-24 09:11:52","updated_at":"2018-07-24 09:11:52"}]

How do I then check if any instance of user_id in the collection is equal to userId which is the current logged in user (also sent via props).

Tried

```
let pf = _.find(this.postFavourite, { "user_id": this.userId})
```

Keep getting undefined as the value of the pf variable even though this.userID is equal to 1.

New to JS and Vue.js so any help would be great.

Here is the vue component code.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <i v-show="this.toggle" @click="onClick" style="color: red" class="fas fa-heart"></i>
        <i v-show="!(this.toggle)" @click="onClick" style="color: white" class="fas fa-heart"></i>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                toggle: 0,
            }
        },

        props: ['postData', 'postFavourite', 'userId'],

        mounted() {
            console.log("Post is :"+ this.postData)
            console.log("User id is: "+ this.userId)
            console.log("Favourite Object is :" +this.postFavourite);

            console.log(this.postFavourite.find(pf => pf.user_id == this.userId));


       },

        methods: {
            onClick() {
                console.log(this.postData);
                this.toggle = this.toggle ? 0 : 1;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

This is how I passed the props to vue

```
<div id="app">
    <favorite :post-data="'{{ $post->id }}'" :post-favourite="'{{Auth::user()->favourite }}'" :user-id="'{{ $post->user->id }}'"></favorite>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using lodash?

Comment: Yes.  It's required in the bootstrap.js.

Comment: Could you post some extra code. Specifically your mounted method and data

Comment: I am just trying to get from the collection wether the post has been favourited by the user so I can set the toggle correctly.

Comment: You have copied and error from an answer below `pf => pf.user_id = this.userId` should be `pf => pf.user_id == this.userId`. Does this resolve the issue?

Comment: Same error as before.

Comment: Altered the error in my post too.  Thanks

Comment: Looks like `this.postFavourite` is not an array. What is the result of you logging this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave up on lodash and find and just messed around with the data in the chrome console to work out how to check the value I wanted.

Then I built a loop to check for the value.
If it found it toggle the like heart on of not leave it off.

This will not be the best way to solve this problem but I'm just pleased I got my first real vue component working.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <i v-show="this.toggle" @click="onClick" style="color: red" class="fas fa-heart"></i>
        <i v-show="!(this.toggle)" @click="onClick" style="color: white" class="fas fa-heart"></i>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['postData', 'postFavourite', 'userId']
        ,

        data() {
            return {
                toggle: 0,
                favs: [],
                id: 0
            }
        },

        mounted () {
            var x
            for(x=0; x < this.postFavourite.length; x++){
                this.favs = this.postFavourite[x];
                if(this.favs['post_id'] == this.postData) {
                    this.toggle = 1
                    this.id = this.favs['id']
                }
            }
        },

        methods: {
            onClick() {
                console.log(this.postData)
                if(this.toggle == 1){
                    axios.post('favourite/delete', {
                        postid: this.id
                    })
                    .then(response => {})
                    .catch(e => {
                        this.errors.push(e)
                    })
                }
                else if(this.toggle == 0){

                    axios.post('favourite', {
                        user: this.userId,
                        post: this.postData
                    })
                    .then(response => {
                        this.id = response.data
                    })
                    .catch(e => {
                        this.errors.push(e)
                    })
                }
                this.toggle = this.toggle ? 0 : 1;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Where I pass my props.

```
<favorite :post-data="'{{ $post->id }}'" 
          :post-favourite="{{ Auth::user()->favourite }}"
          :user-id="'{{ Auth::user()->id }}'"></favorite>
```

Thanks to all that tried to help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find()` directly on `this.postFavourite` like this:

```
this.postFavourite.find(pf => pf.user_id == this.userId);
```

[Here is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22844560/check-if-object-value-exists-within-a-javascript-array-of-objects-and-if-not-add/22844712) another way to do it that might help you as well.

[EDIT]

In order to use `find()` the variable needs to be an array, `this.postFavourite` is sent as a string if you didn't use `v-bind` to pass the prop thats what caused the error.

To pass an array or an object to the component you have to use `v-bind` to tell Vue that it is a JavaScript expression rather than a string. More informations [in the documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Passing-an-Array)

```
<custom-component v-bind:post-favourite="[...array]"></custom-component>
```

Comment: all give this error app.js:1100 [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: this.postFavourite.find is not a function"

Comment: can you share how you pass the props to the component ? to pass an array as prop you have to use `v-bind` I edited the answer. Look at [this documentation link](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Passing-an-Array) on how to implement it

Comment: Added to bottom of post.

Comment: Are you sure that `this.postFavourite` is an array ? like @Josh said in the previous comments. Try with `json_encode(Auth::user()->favourite->toArray())`. You could use a state management library like vuex to simplify passing the values between the componenets and get the data from a controller to format it like you want

Comment: Does it changes something if you send it without the single quotation marks ? not sure if these are necessary. Like this `:post-favourite="{{Auth::user()->favourite }}"` instead of `:post-favourite="'{{Auth::user()->favourite }}'"`

Comment: It is passed as an object and not as json type data.

Comment: In devtools it is postFavourite: Array[1] and the values are droped down below in key value pairs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176675/discussion-between-finchy70-and-belahcel-yanis).

Answer (score 0):

From just the code you provided, I see no issue. However lodash is not required for this problem.

Using ES2015 arrow functions

```
let pf = this.postFavourite.find(item => item.user_id === this.userId);
```

Will find the correct item in your array

You can read more about this function [in the mdn webdocs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: I had tried that but got this error. app.js:1100 [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: this.postFavourite.find is not a function"