# Reactjs: How to check data in array if it is exist or not?

Tags: arrays, reactjs

This is my array

```
let a = [{"id":1,"barcode":"8851907264888"},{"id":2,"barcode":"8857124022072"}];
```

I want to input a barcode and check that if the input barcode is exist in array or not, what should I do?

Comment: Have you tired this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22844560/check-if-object-value-exists-within-a-javascript-array-of-objects-and-if-not-add/22844712

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if object value exists within a Javascript array of objects and if not add a new object to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22844560/check-if-object-value-exists-within-a-javascript-array-of-objects-and-if-not-add)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Array::some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

> The `some()` method tests whether at least one element in the array
> passes the test implemented by the provided function. It returns a
> Boolean value.

```
arr.some(el => el.barcode === barcodeToSearch);
```

```js
const a = [{
  "id": 1,
  "barcode": "8851907264888"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "barcode": "8857124022072"
}];

const hasBarcode = (arr, barcode) => arr.some(el => el.barcode === barcode);

const barcode1 = "1234567890123";
const barcode2 = "8857124022072";

console.log(hasBarcode(a, barcode1)); // false
console.log(hasBarcode(a, barcode2)); // true
```