# How to check multiple values within an array of Typescript objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I am storing a number of objects within the below array in my Typescript project

*(I have removed some data to make the code easier to read)*:

```
workoutExercises = [
    {
      id: 0,
      exerciseComplete: false,
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      exerciseComplete: false,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      exerciseComplete: false,
    },
  ];
```

I am trying to write some code that checks if all the `exerciseComplete` vaues are `TRUE`.

If all of them are `TRUE`, I want to perform a certain action. If at least one of them is `FALSE`, I want to perform a different action.

I'm able to loop through the objects with the below For Loop, but I'm not sure how to check all the `exerciseComplete` values.

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.workoutExercises.length; i++) {
    console.log(this.workoutExercises[i].exerciseComplete);
}
```

Can someone please tell me how I would check the above with this loop?

Comment: Look at [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [`Array.everyt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if object value exists within a Javascript array of objects and if not add a new object to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22844560/check-if-object-value-exists-within-a-javascript-array-of-objects-and-if-not-add)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Array.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

```
workoutExercises.every(exercise => exercise.exerciseComplete)

//returns true if all exercises are complete
```

Answer (score 2):

Array.every() will help you check whether all elements in the array pass or not

The every() method tests whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function. It returns a Boolean value.

```
const isBelowThreshold = (currentValue) => currentValue < 40;

const array1 = [1, 30, 39, 29, 10, 13];

console.log(array1.every(isBelowThreshold));
// expected output: true
```

[Array.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (workoutExercises.some(item => !item.exerciseComplete)) {
    //...
} else {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an array copy where excercises are complete and then compare both sizes

```
let workoutExercisesDone = workoutExercises.filter(exercise => exercise.exerciseComplete); //this will filter yout array by exercises finished
```

then compare if both lenght are equals

```
workoutExercisesDone == workoutExercises //true means that all exercises are done
```