# How to Filter an Array and get the entire data entry?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have,

```
[
  {
    _id: 60673d40ba14f617081bdf4d,
    ImageName: 'Flowers',
    ImagePath: './public/assets/img/1.jpg',
    Description: 'A cool Image',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: 60673e099d76ef16a8ec4588,
    ImageName: 'Water Bubble Colors',
    ImagePath: './public/assets/img/2.jpg',
    Description: 'Wallpapers',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: 60673e39f10c4a12a0f4ea31,
    ImageName: 'Egg Silhouette Wallpaper',
    ImagePath: './public/assets/img/3.jpg',
    Description: 'Wallpapers',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: 60673e4a15d9bb18a01312df,
    ImageName: 'Pencil BW ',
    ImagePath: './public/assets/img/4.jpg',
    Description: 'Wallpapers',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: 60673e6c6de9bb1bf8c65d25,
    ImageName: 'Water',
    ImagePath: './public/assets/img/5.jpg',
    Description: 'Wallpapers',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: 60673e8a8af58b1fb8b11596,
    ImageName: 'Dining Plate',
    ImagePath: './public/assets/img/6.jpg',
    Description: 'Wallpapers',
    __v: 0
  }
]
```

and `var id = req.params.id` which basically is `60673e8a8af58b1fb8b11596`.
Now how can I filter the array with the `id` variable I have and get the entire Object which has the id? I want the entire object with _id,ImageName, ImagePath, __v and Description.

I searched a lot,found `array.filter` method, but its so complexed and didnt help me and i got even more confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) checking the id:

```js
var data = [
  {
    _id: '60673d40ba14f617081bdf4d',
    ImageName: 'Flowers',
    ImagePath: './public/assets/img/1.jpg',
    Description: 'A cool Image',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: '60673e099d76ef16a8ec4588',
    ImageName: 'Water Bubble Colors',
    ImagePath: './public/assets/img/2.jpg',
    Description: 'Wallpapers',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: '60673e39f10c4a12a0f4ea31',
    ImageName: 'Egg Silhouette Wallpaper',
    ImagePath: './public/assets/img/3.jpg',
    Description: 'Wallpapers',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: '60673e4a15d9bb18a01312df',
    ImageName: 'Pencil BW ',
    ImagePath: './public/assets/img/4.jpg',
    Description: 'Wallpapers',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: '60673e6c6de9bb1bf8c65d25',
    ImageName: 'Water',
    ImagePath: './public/assets/img/5.jpg',
    Description: 'Wallpapers',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: '60673e8a8af58b1fb8b11596',
    ImageName: 'Dining Plate',
    ImagePath: './public/assets/img/6.jpg',
    Description: 'Wallpapers',
    __v: 0
  }
]
var id = '60673e8a8af58b1fb8b11596'; //req.params.id

var res = data.filter(d => d._id == id);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Note: `_id` should have been a string. In the original question it wasn't.

Answer (score 2):

SO lets say the above array is called `foo` ;

```
let item = foo.find(e=>e._id == your_id);
```

What this does is looking in the foo array and will return the first condition that satisfies the callback passed

However if you wanted to get the same result from the mongodb database instead you could perform a query like this:

`collection.find({_id:ObjectID(your_id)})`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to get the element. It will directly return the element. If you need multiple solution to find the Element in array. [Check if object value exists within a Javascript array of objects and if not add a new object to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22844560/check-if-object-value-exists-within-a-javascript-array-of-objects-and-if-not-add/63716844#63716844)

```js
const arr = [
  {
    _id: "60673d40ba14f617081bdf4d",
    ImageName: "Flowers",
    ImagePath: "./public/assets/img/1.jpg",
    Description: "A cool Image",
    __v: 0,
  },
  {
    _id: "60673e099d76ef16a8ec4588",
    ImageName: "Water Bubble Colors",
    ImagePath: "./public/assets/img/2.jpg",
    Description: "Wallpapers",
    __v: 0,
  },
  {
    _id: "60673e39f10c4a12a0f4ea31",
    ImageName: "Egg Silhouette Wallpaper",
    ImagePath: "./public/assets/img/3.jpg",
    Description: "Wallpapers",
    __v: 0,
  },
  {
    _id: "60673e4a15d9bb18a01312df",
    ImageName: "Pencil BW ",
    ImagePath: "./public/assets/img/4.jpg",
    Description: "Wallpapers",
    __v: 0,
  },
  {
    _id: "60673e6c6de9bb1bf8c65d25",
    ImageName: "Water",
    ImagePath: "./public/assets/img/5.jpg",
    Description: "Wallpapers",
    __v: 0,
  },
  {
    _id: "60673e8a8af58b1fb8b11596",
    ImageName: "Dining Plate",
    ImagePath: "./public/assets/img/6.jpg",
    Description: "Wallpapers",
    __v: 0,
  },
];

var id = "60673e8a8af58b1fb8b11596";

const result = arr.find(({ _id }) => _id === id);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using mongoose. You can use `findById(id)`. For ex: `Model.findById(id)`