# Map and If statement unexpected behaviour

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, if-statement

The results I want to achieve are:

If the entered name is already on the array "persons", show an alert "Name already exist".

The code is not working, because I keep on getting the alert message all the time.
I think the condition comparison variable (personObject.name ) is wrong.

Can someone explain how this should be done?

Without the condition, the names ad added propperly into the array.

```
//Condition
 if (persons.map((person) => person.name === personObject.name) )
 {
    alert("Name already exist");
   
 }
    else
    {
    
    //*/

    setPersons(persons.concat(personObject))
    setNewName('')
  console.log(persons) 
}
```

[Code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-shockley-ywxxj?file=/src/App.js)
Full code:

```
const App = () => {
  //Reminder: current state, function that updates it, initial state.
  const [persons, setPersons] = useState([
    //The array persons is empty at start
  ]);
  const [newName, setNewName] = useState('');

  //adding new persons

  const addPerson = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    /* complete the addPerson function for creating new persons */
    const personObject = {
      name: newName,

      id: persons.length + 1,
    };

    //Condition
    if (persons.map((person) => person.name === personObject.name)) {
      alert('Name already exist');
    } else {
      //*/

      setPersons(persons.concat(personObject));
      setNewName('');
      console.log(persons);
    }
  };

  const handlePersonChange = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    setNewName(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Phonebook</h2>

      <form onSubmit={addPerson}>
        <div>
          name:
          <input value={newName} onChange={handlePersonChange} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <button type="submit">add</button>
        </div>
      </form>
      <h2>Numbers</h2>

      {console.log(persons)}
      <ul>
        {persons.map((person) => (
          <li key={person.id}>{person.name}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if object value exists within a Javascript array of objects and if not add a new object to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22844560/check-if-object-value-exists-within-a-javascript-array-of-objects-and-if-not-add)

Comment: Use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) instead of `map`

Comment: `map` returns an array. An array is an object. An object is true. Did you mean to write `map(..).length`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are checking condition with using `map` and `map` will return new array so if condition will be always true.

So instead of map you should use `some` like below:-

```js
persons.some((person) => person.name === personObject.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `filter` method that filters an array and returns you an array with items matching the condition, if this new array is empty it means no items matches it :

```
let alreadyExists = persons.filter(person => person.name === personObject.name)

if (alreadyExists.length > 0) {
  alert("Name already exist")
} else {
  setPersons(persons.concat(personObject))
  setNewName('')
  console.log(persons) 
}
```