# send my CheckBox list value to a Json

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, checkbox

I have a simple and strange question.
I have a drop box list that i made with ng-repeat. (Below code)

```
 <ul>
 <li ng-repeat="item in formLIST.ContractType">
    <input  type="checkbox" ng-click="checkItems(item)" value={{item.ls_ItemIndex}} >{{item.ls_ItemValue}}
 </li>
 </ul>
```

And this is my Angularjs code (Below)

```
$scope.listitem=[];
$scope.checkItems = function (item) {
    $scope.listitem.push({
        item: item.ls_ItemValue      
    });
```

And my question is this:
I want to know, when i check OR uncheck these beautiful small boxes, it adds or remove the value of it in my JSON file.

And now when i click on my check boxes, it will be add in my JSON. But if i click on it again for unchecked it, it will be add again in my JSON file.
My code can add them several times. except remove it.
And i want to add these beautifuls just once.

Comment: Check here on how to push to an array only if the value does not exist. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988349/array-push-if-does-not-exist

Comment: so you want to push if its selected and pop if its already there?

Comment: I think you might want this: http://jsbin.com/ImAqUC/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
$scope.checkItems = function (item) {
    var idx = $scope.listitem.indexOf(item.ls_ItemIndex);

    if(idx == -1) // not selected
       $scope.listitem.push(item.ls_ItemIndex);
    else // selected
       $scope.listitem.splice(idx,1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you use ng-model:

```
<ul>
 <li ng-repeat="item in formLIST.ContractType">
    <input  type="checkbox" ng-model="item.Is_ItemValue" />{{item.ls_ItemValue}}
 </li>
 </ul>

  <!-- selected list -->
  <ol>
  <li ng-repeat="item in formLIST.ContractType | filter: {Is_ItemValue:true}"> {{ item }}</li>
  </ol>
```