# avoid adding duplicating items in ng-repeat collection, in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have ng click event like this :

```
$scope.submitInfo = function myfunction() {
        var itemToAdd = {
            Id : generateUUID(),
            Name: $scope.Name,
            Email: $scope.Email,
            Phone: $scope.Phone
        };
        $scope.Info.push(itemToAdd);
    }
```

my problem is, i want to check if the same `ID` or `Name` is not already exist in `$scope.Info` collection.

i am purly foucs on angular.js, i am looking for best solution for this kind of scenario

Comment: you'll have to iterate through the collection and compare each row to the data being added.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Array .push() if does not exist?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988349/array-push-if-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [$filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$filter).

Something like this:

```
$scope.submitInfo = function myfunction() {
    var itemToAdd = {
        Id : generateUUID(),
        Name: $scope.Name,
        Email: $scope.Email,
        Phone: $scope.Phone
    };
    var foundElement = $filter('filter')($scope.Info, {Name: $scope.Name}, true);

    if (foundElement.length === 0) {
        $scope.Info.push(itemToAdd);
    }
};
```

Of course, you'll need to inject $filter in your controller/factory/whatever

Answer (score 0):

Try this - Inside your submit function write below code  i.e

```
$scope.submitInfo = function myfunction() {
    var itemToAdd = {
        Id : generateUUID(),
        Name: $scope.Name,
        Email: $scope.Email,
        Phone: $scope.Phone
    };
    if(($scope.Info.indexOf(itemToAdd.id) != -1) || ($scope.Info.indexOf(itemToAdd.Name) != -1) {
         $scope.Info.push(itemToAdd);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the native Javascript filter (not supported by IE8) to check if there is an element with that name:

```
var duplicates = $scope.Info.filter(function(item) {
    return item.Name = $scope.Name;
});
var nameExists = duplicates.length > 0;
```

And your complete method:

```
$scope.submitInfo = function myfunction() {
    var duplicates = $scope.Info.filter(function(item) {
        return item.Id = $scope.Name;
    });
    var nameExists = duplicates.length > 0;

    if (!nameExists) {
        var itemToAdd = {
            Id : generateUUID(),
            Name: $scope.Name,
            Email: $scope.Email,
            Phone: $scope.Phone
        };
        $scope.Info.push(itemToAdd);
    }
}
```