# Difference between find() and filter().shift() on javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I recently starting to drop underscore/lodash overuse on (some of) my projects and realize that there's no full support of [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method in browsers. What's the difference between ES6 method [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and using .shift() over [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) results

```
var user = users.find(function() { ... } );
```

or

```
var user = users.filter(function() { ... } ).shift();
```

I imagine there's obvious optimization over "find" method (stop iterating on fist match), but can I get unexpected results using second approach? Should I use the [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill) instead? Why?

Comment: what unexpected results?

Comment: The shift function removes the first element of the array and returns it. The filter function creates a new array. I don't  see why this could be a problem. Anyone?

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Apart from the obvious (and noticeable) overhead, yes, the results might vary. `filter` runs till the end of the array, and invokes its callback on every item; in contrast to `find` which stops after having found one. When the callback throws an exception on one of these additionally iterated elements, the outcome is different.
I don't see any good reason not to use `find`.

Comment: IE doesn't support 'find'.

Comment: @hanesjw That's no reason not to use `find`, only a reason to install the [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill)

Comment: It's the reason not to use IE.

Comment: note also that `filter` returns an `array` , while `find` return an `object`

Comment: @Bergi Accroding th [**MDN Docs**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) `.find()` also invokes callback on every item as well till the end of index. Might've missed something?

Comment: @ambianBeing "*until it finds one where `callback` returns `true`*". Or the end of the array, when it doesn't find such an item.

Comment: typescript cannot infer types when you use `arr.find`. But it can infer the type when you use `arr.filter()[0]`

Comment: @CüneytAliustaoğlu `find` works [just fine in TypeScript](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es2015.core.d.ts#L31-L32) and can also infer the result type. You might want to [ask a separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) if it doesn't work for you, please include your ts config.

Comment: @Bergi I didn't say it doesn't work with TypeScript. Of course it does however TypeScript cannot "infer" the type with find.

Comment: @CüneytAliustaoğlu I'm saying that the *type inference* works fine for `find` in exactly the same way as for `filter` - see the example playground I linked

Answer (score 24):

Use a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill); `users.filter(function() { ... } ).shift();` is throwing cycles away while triggering unnecessary garbage collection.

- `filter` scans the entire array and creates another array
- `shift` now has to change all the indexes on the temp array

A slightly less wasteful pattern would be to use `users.filter(function() { ... } )[0]`

Comment: The slightly less wasteful pattern is going to be painful if the array can be empty.

Comment: @JackBlack You should be more descriptive. How is it going to be a pain? If `users` is empty in the example above, you will get `undefined`, which seems OK?

Comment: You won't be able to access the first item in the array via [0] if there are no items, aka array is empty.

Comment: @JackBlack That doesn't make sense, yes, you get undefined, but no errors. It means your filter returned no results and is a fine result.