# Javascript array.find object by property value

Tags: javascript, arrays

a) Is there any difference between the methods bellow (performance wise)?

b) Does this (.find) function iterates over all objects in the array?

c) Is there yet another syntax for this function?

```
#1 console.log(cres.find(o => o.name === refname));

#2 console.log(cres.find(function(o){return o.name===refname;}));
```

I'm looking for the most efficient way to find an object by it's property value in a large array. So, implementing a custom function (I.e:BTREE) would be a better approach?

Thx

**UPDATE:** Besides the "down vote". I've learned that the case in #1 is just a fancy notation for functions (Es6). So basically both cases are the same.

Anyways, It does not explains if the .find function iterates over all objects in the array and if that's the case a custom implementation would be more performatic...

Comment: https://jsperf.com/ test and find out

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44030645/are-arrow-functions-faster-more-performant-lighter-than-ordinary-standalone-f

Comment: @epascarello It's not necessary to test because I want find out a) which is the method used for the build in function and b) I've no knowledge of the es6 standard. So your comment and the down vote does not helped a lot....

Comment: Lol  you said you wanted to know what was faster so you could have tested it. And the link I posted told you if they were different.

Comment: And if you would read the documentation for find you would know if it stopped or searched all.

Comment: In reality fastest would be to pre index everything and look it up by the key.

Comment: And the funny thing is. I did not down vote you. Lol.

Comment: @epascarello It's ok man. please stop flooding the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) / c) There is no difference, option 1 is just using ES6 syntax.
You can checkout the docs here: http://es6-features.org/#ExpressionBodies

b) `.find` will iterate over the array until it finds a result then it will stop. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33759109/difference-between-find-and-filter-shift-on-javascript)

Comment: Thanx. Thats exactly what I was looking for. So now I have a direction to follow.