# How to select an element in JSON array and bind it to the view in ionic 3?

Tags: android, json, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am making an app in `ionic 3` and I am trying to fetch data from an url.

This is my code in **data.ts** and my data provider:

```
   getVehicleStatus() {
    return this.http.get<VehicleStatus>(this.url);
  }
```

**This is my vehicle class:**

```
class VehicleStatus {
    status: string;
    plate: string;
    code: string;
    message: string;
}
```

I am calling the method into my **home.ts** file.

```
  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log(this.getStatus('test3'));
  }

  getStatus(plate: string) {
    this.dataService.getVehicleStatus()
      .subscribe((data: VehicleStatus) => this.vehiclestatus = [{ ...data }]);
  }
```

To test out if everything works I hard code a license plate number to log it into my chrome developer tools. It said `'Undefined'`.

This is how the json data looks like:

```
[{"status":"P","plate":"test2","code:"MGP150151","message":"fail"}
,{"status":"P","plate":"test3","code":"MGP160298","message":"fail"}
,{"status":"P","plate":"test4","code":"MGP140085","message":"succes"}
,{"status":"O","plate":"test5","code":"MGP150175","message":"succes"}]
```

**I should get this object back:**

```
{"status":"P","plate":"test3","code":"MGP160298","message":"fail"}
```

But it doesn't work and got the message undefined.

I have used the following source:

https://angular.io/guide/http

How can I search in the array and bind it to my `HTML` page in `ionic 3`?.

Can someone point me in the right direction?.

Kind regards .

Comment: What field are you filtering on? `plate` or `code`?

Comment: On the field `plate`

Comment: What does `this.url` return? An array or an Object?

Comment: An array with json objects have a look at the json data. The url is working fine I tested it with postman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The responsibility to `find` the `VehicleStatus` from the list should be of the service rather than of the Component itself.

Consider changing your Service Implementation to take up that responsibility. You can use the `map` operator to transform the response to return the `VehicleStatus` found based on the `plate` that will be passed as an arg while calling the `getVehicleStatus` method.

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

getVehicleStatus(plate): Observable<VehicleStatus> {
  return this.http.get<VehicleStatus[]>(this.url)
    .pipe(
      map(statuses => statuses.find(status => status.plate === plate))
    );
}
```

Then in your home.ts:

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
  this.getStatus('test3');
}

getStatus(plate: string) {
  this.dataService.getVehicleStatus(plate)
    .subscribe((data: VehicleStatus) => this.vehiclestatus = data);
}
```

Comment: filter will not be the suitable option in this case

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33759109/difference-between-find-and-filter-shift-on-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You need **[array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)** to get the matching value, which will return the first matching element from the array

```
 this.vehiclestatus =  data.find(vehicle=>vehicle.plate === plate);
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. I get the following error when I added your solution: `Property 'find' does not exist on type 'VehicleStatus'`

Comment: are you sure you are applying filter on data not on  VehicleStatus?

Comment: Yes have a look in the **data.ts** file

Comment: can you post what you get inside console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

Comment: I get the following message when I add it `Cannot find name 'data'.`

Comment: what? that's strange, where did you get the json data then?

Comment: I have used the example in the Angular documentation:

`config: Config;

showConfig() {
  this.configService.getConfig()
    // clone the data object, using its known Config shape
    .subscribe((data: Config) => this.config = { ...data });
}`