# Detect duplicate key and replace its value within an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am new to javascript.I am trying to build an array with key value pair and I have done that successfully.

This is my current output:

[image: My current Output:]

Now what I want is to check the key of each object in the array.If the key already exists then the value for that corresponding key will be updated else a new key with its value will be inserted.

My code:

```
function pushToAry(name, val) {
//alert("In the array");
var flag=1;
  kony.print("name-->"+name+"  val-->"+val);
   for (var i in ARY) {
    kony.print("ARY[i].name-->"+ARY[i].name+"  ARY[i].val-->"+ARY[i].val);
     if (ARY[i].name == name) {
     kony.print("In if");
        ARY[i].val = val;
        flag=0;
        break; //Stop this loop, we found it!

     }else{
       kony.print("In else");
     }
   }


   if(flag==1){
   kony.print("flag is 1-->"+flag);
   var obj = {};
   obj[name] = val;
   ARY.push(obj);
    }
}
```

My above code is not working.**ARY[i].name and ARY[i].val is coming undefined**.

ARY is a global array defined as `ARY=[];`

What wrong I am doing here?

Comment: Your data structure is a bit odd.  You have an array of objects, each with 1 property.  It sounds like this is what you actually want to do, but a Javascript Object natively lets you do something very similar: `var foo = {}; foo[name] = val;`

Comment: Please look into this post --> http://stackoverflow.com/a/1988361/4361743

Comment: Downvoter care to explain??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```js
function pushToAry(name, val) {
        for (var i = 0; i < ARY.length; i++) {
            if (ARY[i].hasOwnProperty(name)) {
                ARY[i][name] = val;
                return;
            }
        }
    
        var obj = {};
        obj[name] = val;
        ARY.push(obj);
    }

    function init() {
        ARY = [];
        pushToAry("Label", 1000.0);
        pushToAry("Label", 1000.1);
        console.log(`ARY has ${ARY.length} entries`);
        console.log(`ARY[0].Label: ${ARY[0].Label}`);
    }

    document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", init, false );
```

Comment: giving compilation error Parse error. missing ; after for-loop initializer  in the line for (let elem of ARY)

Comment: compilation error resolves after i change for (let elem of ARY) to for (var elem in ARY)

Comment: Interesting.  What browser are you using?

Comment: I am doing this in a hybrid mobile app using kony studio

Comment: this code is not working :( ....still duplicate values are getting inserted

Comment: I guess it's not ECMA6

Comment: Let me modify it for use with pre ECMA 6 env

Comment: fINALLY WORKED...THANKS

Comment: You might want to consider revisiting your data structure.  In more than a few instances it will cause you to write more code than you would need if you used a more native structure.  (For instance, this function could almost be re-written as `function pushToAry(name, val) { ARY[name] = val; }` (If course, you would lose the ability to have duplicates - but that is fairly easily solved)

Comment: Yes surely I will have a look at it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127345/discussion-between-kgandroid-and-tibrogargan).