# Push item into new array if there isn't a duplicated value.

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax

I'm getting names back from this array. There are duplicated names (example: "Kenny") that are returned two times and I only want to push it into the new array once. I'm kinda lost in the process. Here's what I have done so far.

```
var newArr = [];



$.ajax({
    url: 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list//od6/public/values?alt=json',
    success: function(data){
        var entryPoint = data.feed.entry;
        // data.feed.entry entry to arrays 
        for (i = 0; i < entryPoint.length; i++){
            var fName = entryPoint[i].gsx$firstname.$t;
            var lName = entryPoint[i].gsx$lastname.$t;
            var email = entryPoint[i].gsx$email.$t;
            var total = entryPoint[i].gsx$totalordered.$t;


            newArr.push(fName)

        }

    }


})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array.push() if does not exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988349/array-push-if-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
var newArr = [];
var found;

$.ajax({
url: 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list//od6/public/values?alt=json',
success: function(data)
{
    var entryPoint = data.feed.entry;
    // data.feed.entry entry to arrays

    for (i = 0; i < entryPoint.length; i++)
    {
        var fName = entryPoint[i].gsx$firstname.$t;
        var lName = entryPoint[i].gsx$lastname.$t;
        var email = entryPoint[i].gsx$email.$t;
        var total = entryPoint[i].gsx$totalordered.$t;

        found = false;

        // Check the array for the name
        for(var i=0; i < newArr.length; i++)
        {
            if(newArr[i] == fName)
            {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        // If name not found, add it
        if(!found) newArr.push(fName)
    }
}
});
```

Comment: You are right, thanks for the tips, I edited for `true`.

Answer (score 3):

newArr.indexOf(value) will return -1 if not found

Answer (score 0):

If `newArr` needs to contain unique values, it should be a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), not an Array. You can put the names into a `Set` by passing the constructor an array:

```
var newSet = new Set(entryPoint.map(entry => entry.gsx$firstname.$t));
```

Any name that's already been added to the set will be skipped. You can then get an `Iterator` to work with the stored names using `newSet.values()`, or, if you're more comfortable, use it to create an array based on the set:

```
var newArr = [...newSet.values()];
// or var newArr = Array.from(newSet.values()); if you can't use destructuring
```

All that being said, `Set` isn't available in Internet Explorer. But you can polyfill it with, among other things, [polyfill.io](https://polyfill.io).