# Prevent pushing array in other array angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have one array like below,

```
                    $scope.unassociatedResults = [{
                                matchName : 'Dummy_data',
                                address : 'Dummy_data',
                                country : 'Dummy_data',
                                listSourceCountryName : 'Dummy_data',
                                screeningCategory : 'Dummy_data'
                    },
                    {
                                matchName : 'Dummy_data2',
                                address : 'Dummy_data2',
                                country : 'Dummy_data2',
                                listSourceCountryName : 'Dummy_data2',
                                screeningCategory : 'Dummy_data2'
                    },
                   {
                                matchName : 'Dummy_data3',
                                address : 'Dummy_data3',
                                country : 'Dummy_data3',
                                listSourceCountryName : 'Dummy_data3',
                                screeningCategory : 'Dummy_data3'
                    },
                    {
                                matchName : 'Dummy_data4',
                                address : 'Dummy_data4',
                                country : 'Dummy_data4',
                                listSourceCountryName : 'Dummy_data4',
                                screeningCategory : 'Dummy_data4'
                    },
            ];
```

Now, I have other array which has parameters like below

```
           $scope.unassociatedResultsNewArray = [{
                            matchName : 'Dummy_data',
                            address : 'Dummy_data',
                            country : 'Dummy_data',
                            listSourceCountryName : 'Dummy_data',
                            screeningCategory : 'Dummy_data'
                }];
```

how can I check atleast two, three values of new array to existing array list or how can I compare whole new array with existing array list, to avoid the duplication. In my case I have no id or no primary something like to check or to compare data. So I need to check whole array with existing array list.

How can I check it in angularjs or in javascript ?

Comment: You can try to stringify it and compare both objects.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array.push() if does not exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988349/array-push-if-does-not-exist)

Comment: Stringify objects and compare it `JSON.stringify({name: "ss"}) === JSON.stringify({name: "ss"})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; ++i) {
    for (var j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {
        if (JSON.stringify(array2[j]) === JSON.stringify(array1[i]))
            array2.splice(j, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess you meant JSON.stringify(array2[j] )=== JSON.stringify(array1[i])).

Will stringify ensure the order of object's attribute, since it isn't array?

Comment: Yes, I wanted same, except slice , i want to push arry2 in array1 in its next index. I have tried below code,
but it is not working


 for (var i = 0; i < $scope.unassociatedResults.length; ++i) {
   for (var j = 0; j < $scope.unassociatedResultsNewArray.length; j++) {
    if (JSON.stringify($scope.unassociatedResultsNewArray[j]) === JSON.stringify($scope.unassociatedResults[i])){
     console.log("hello");
     $scope.unassociatedResultsNewArray.splice(j, 1);
    } else {
     $scope.unassociatedResults.push(j, 1);
    }
    
   }
  }