# how to use reduce function to simplify this code

Tags: javascript

I've an array: `var old_array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

If `5` exists in this array, remove it otherwise add it.

```
var new_array = [];
var number_existed = false;
for(var i=0,len=old_array.length;i<len;i++) {
   if(old_array[i] == 5) {
   new_array = old_array.slice(i+1);
   number_existed = true;
   break;
   } else {
      new_array.push( old_array[i] );
   }
}

if(!number_existed) {
    new_array.push(5);
}
```

It works, but I need improvements. How can I improve this code. I wanna see `reduce` function in action but just not able to come up with anything logical.

Comment: Why not if on a `contains()` or `indexOf()` and based off of that, push it in the array, or splice it out?

Comment: *it works* ... so [1, 1, 5, 1, 1] should result in [1, 1] ?

Comment: @JonasWilms yeah, I didn't see that one coming, thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array.push() if does not exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988349/array-push-if-does-not-exist)

Comment: Jeto's answer should solve this.  There is no real reason to use `reduce` for this, as it would just complicate things.  If you were just filtering out the existing `5`s, `reduce` would be an overcomplicated but not unreasonable alternative to `filter`.  But since you also want to add a `5` if it's not there, your accumulator is going to need to carry extra state -- or you would store it somewhere worse.  Such code is feasible, but quite ugly compared to the alternatives.

Comment: @ScottSauyet I understand now, thanks. a simple filter and a boolean was all that was needed. thanks. but I'm going to accept Jonas' ans coz it's a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 let fiveFound = false;
 const result = input.filter(it => it !== 5 || !(fiveFound = true));
 if(!fiveFound) result.push(5);
```

`reduce` won't help you here.

Answer (score 3):

You can check if the element already exists with [`Array.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes), then either [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) it to remove it, or append it using [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_array_literals):

```js
function addOrRemove5(arr) {
  return arr.includes(5) ? arr.filter(v => v !== 5) : [...arr, 5];
}

console.log(addOrRemove5([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
console.log(addOrRemove5([1, 2, 3, 4]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `reduce` is not best approach, because reduce is used to return a single item. In my solution I use findIndex and apply your logic.

```js
function usingFunctions(old) {
 var index = old.findIndex( function(it) { return it == 5  } );
 var new_arr = old.slice( index + 1 );
 if( index < 0 ) new_arr.push(5);
 return new_arr
}

var old = [1, 2, 6, 8, 5, 3, 6, 9];
console.log( usingFunctions(old) );
old = [1, 2, 6, 8, 3, 6, 9];
console.log( usingFunctions(old) );
```

Answer (score 1):

One more solution, expanding on my comment:

> Jeto's answer should solve this. There is no real reason to use reduce for this, as it would just complicate things. If you were just filtering out the existing 5s, `reduce` would be an overcomplicated but not unreasonable alternative to `filter`. But since you also want to add a 5 if it's not there, your accumulator is going to need to carry extra state -- or you would store it somewhere worse. Such code is feasible, but quite ugly compared to the alternatives.

Here is what such uglier code might look like:

```js
const addOrRemove5 = (arr) => { 
  const {found, xs} = arr.reduce(
    ({found, xs}, x) => x === 5 ? {found: true, xs} : {found, xs: [...xs, x]},
    {found: false, xs: []}
  )
  return found ? xs : [...xs, 5]
}

console.log(addOrRemove5([1, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5])) //=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
console.log(addOrRemove5([1, 2, 3, 4]))       //=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

This uses an accumulator that looks like `{found: boolean, xs: [number]}`, starting with `{found: false, xs: []}`, updating `found` to be `true` on each `5`, and adding each non-5 to the values.  Then after that runs, we return either the existing values or the existing values and an additional `5`, depending on the value of `found`.

Again, this is much uglier than Jeto's solution.  I would not recommend it here.  But such techniques are not terribly uncommon when you need carry additional information as well as reducing a value.  And a variant of this could let you work only with expressions and not any statements, by putting the resulting `{found, xs}` object in a default parameter:

```
const addOrRemove5 = (
  arr, 
  {found, xs} = arr.reduce(
    ({found, xs}, x) => x === 5 ? {found: true, xs} : {found, xs: [...xs, x]},
    {found: false, xs: []}
  )
) => found ? xs : [...xs, 5]
```

Again this is not recommended in this case, but it's a useful trick to know.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `reduce()` just use `filter()`

```js
var old_array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

var new_array = old_array.filter(x => x === 5);
console.log(new_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find it using `indexOf` to get the index, and remove it using `splice` or add it using `push`

```js
var array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

function modify_array(value, array) {
  let idx = array.indexOf(value)
  idx > -1 ? array.splice(idx, 1) : array.push(value)
  return array
}

// Test cases

// Remove 5
console.log(modify_array(5, array1))
// Add 10
console.log(modify_array(10, array1))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* want to use `reduce()`:

```
  function togglePresenceOfFive(array) {
  if (array.length === 0) { // Reduce can't handle this case because the loop never runs
        return [5];
    } else {
        const reduceResult = array.reduce((acc, next, index, arr) => {
            const isLast = index === arr.length - 1;

            if (next === 5) {
                return {
                    newArray: acc.newArray,
                    fiveFound: true
                };
            } else if (!acc.fiveFound && isLast) {
                return {
                    newArray: acc.newArray.concat(next, 5),
                    fiveFound: false
                }
            } else {
                return {
                    newArray: acc.newArray.concat(next),
                    fiveFound: acc.fiveFound
                };
            }
            },
            { newArray: [], fiveFound: false }
        );

        return reduceResult.newArray; 
    }
}

  return reduceResult.newArray;
}
```

But this is more readable in my opinion (assuming you don't mind mutating the original array):

```
function togglePresenceOfFive(array) {
    const indexOfFive = array.indexOf(5);

    if (indexOfFive > -1) {
        array.splice(indexOfFive, 1);
    } else {
        array.push(5);
    }

    return array;
}
```

Comment: See my answer for a cleaner version of the same `reduce` idea.  It also deals with the empty array case by giving a starting value to the accumulator.  But of course the point is that this is likely overkill.