# Javascript update array value if exists otherwise push new array to object

Tags: javascript, jquery, multidimensional-array, array-push

I am trying to update a value in the array if it is found, if it isn't then add a new array to it.

Here's some code I have been trying:

```
var cartItems = {};
var items = []
cartItems.items = items;
$('.proAdd').click(function(){
var name = $(this).attr("data-name");
var price = parseFloat($(this).attr("data-price"));
var quantity = parseInt($(this).attr("data-quantity"));

var item = {"name": name,"price": price,"quantity": quantity}

items.forEach(function(item) {
if (item.name === name) {
item.quantity = 2
return; 
}else{
cartItems.items.push(item);
}
});
```

In this version noting gets pushed. If I take out the else branch then it does update it but also pushes it. I have created a [fiddle for this](https://jsfiddle.net/w5s34tL2/).

Also tried this but it says x.quantity is not defined:

```
var index = items.findIndex(x => x.name==name)
if (index != -1){
x.quantity = 2
}
else {
cartItems.items.push(item);
}
```

Comment: `items[index].quantity = 2`

Comment: If `name` is unique shouldn't `items` be an object keyed to `name`? That would make this problem go away.

Comment: @cgTag that solved it, thank you! Could accept as answer would be appreciated if you could explain if I'd run into any browser compatibility issues as well.

Comment: No browser issues here, and this was a syntax mistake so I'd rather not post an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array.push() if does not exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988349/array-push-if-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `index` stores the index of an item, and `x` is a temporary value which is unavailable after that line. Use `find` instead, and make sure you're looking at the same `items` each time:

```
var item = cartItems.items.find(x => x.name == name);
if (item) {
  item.quantity = 2;
} else {
  cartItems.items.push(item);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, getting cartItems.find is not a function. Cheers.