# Collision tracking

Tags: javascript, object, collision

I am adding collisions in a P5.js project, but I need to somehow track which objects have collided with others so I can create various "relationships" for them.

Should I just put the object data into an array? I thought maybe each object should track it's own relationships...

```
crossPaths(other) {
    let d = dist(this.pos.x,this.pos.y,other.pos.x,other.pos.y);
    d < (this.size/2 + other.size/2) ? true : false;
}

createRelationship(other) {
    this.relationShip = other;
    this.relationShipList.push(this.relationShip);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it depends on **what you want to achieve with the collision system**. The current approach gives more importance to *"easily get collisions per object"* rather than *"keep a log of all collisions"*.

Here is your approach and an alternative:

#### Your approach:

Every collision is pushed into `object.relationShipList` of the colliding object.

- Easy and fast way to fetch all collisions **per object**: Only read `object.relationShipList`.
- Very hard way to get a log of all collisions: Getting a log of all collisions would require calling `object.relationShipList` **on every object** and saving each collision in a new array.
- Will lead to data duplication: If there are multiple objects colliding, each object will generate its own collision.

#### Alternative that I would chose:

Every collision is pushed into a global array. When object `a` collides with object `b`, you register a `window.collisionSystem.push([a, b])`.

- A little bit more complex way to get collisions per object: You would need to query `window.collisionSystem` to get collisions. This can be achieved with a function like

```
function getCollisionsFor(ob) {
  return window.collisionSystem.filter(e => {
    if (e[0] === ob || e[1] === ob) return true;
  })
}
```

And then call it like `getCollisionsFor([objectIWant])` to get a new array of collisions for the `objectIWant` object.

- Easy way to keep track of all collisions without duplicate data: This is *-of course-* the `window.collisionsSystem` array.
- Easy way to prune data: Just `window.collisionSystem = [];` to clear up the object.

*Recommended reading about this particular question in Game Engines, see: https://books.google.com/books?id=EwlpDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT726&lpg=PT726&dq=havok+collision+tracking&source=bl&ots=Eav72q2T95&sig=ACfU3U15UvAqvf4FmjYKOAsm1CPMlyaFQA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi559zSgJDmAhXHnuAKHQv0ATAQ6AEwCXoECAwQAQ#v=onepage&q=havok%20collision%20tracking&f=false*

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried pushing to arrays already but because collisions/overlaps happen for a number of milliseconds, the pairs were being added over and over again. I am now trying a version using pairs as an object where the array is checked first to make sure they have not already been added.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988349/array-push-if-does-not-exist